# Does this code have the potential to cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript

I have this example code

```
EventHandlerFieldUpdate.prototype.updateScreenChanged = function($newValue) {
    this.bound.parent().find('.changedFieldMessage').click(jQuery.proxy(function() 
        {
        // some uninteresting stuff happening
        this.bound.val($newValue);
        },this));
    }
```

What happens is if the event is called the value of the form gets updated with the provided value. nothing to worry about there.

What I am worried about is a memory leak because this is an app that might run for many hours on a day in a single instance.

When the event listener click is removed by the `jquery` and the click even cleaned and the event listener I made myself is cleaned, will the lexicon of `updateScreenChanged` persist or not?

would it be better to pass `$newValue` to a `this.newvalue` so the newvalue will get cleaned up after the object is wiped?

Comment: You could just test it?

Comment: how would i test if the lexicon is still there? thats one thing I cannot find out how. and if both objects are wiped I would have no logical accesspoint to `$newvalue`